# Get N random hits from Elasticsearch which match my query

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have a ElasticSearch data of ~5000 total hits, which match my query. Now I want 10 random hits from ~5000 hits.

As of now I am generating random numbers from 0-5000 10 times and I am querying ES 10 times with the generated random numbers.

I am doing this with help of **from** and **size** key words of ES. By assigning random number to **from** and **size** as 1

I want this to be done in one query. Is there a way to do this in ES ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using a [`function_score` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#function-random) (using `random_score`):

```
GET /_search
{
    "query": {
        "function_score": {
            "random_score": {
                "seed": 5000,
                "field": "_seq_no"
            }
        }
    }
}
```